# Email Address Varification Application in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email

I am getting 555 syntax error in mailfrom

```
SendData(tcpSocket, string.Format("MAIL From: {0}\r\n", MailFrom));
if (!CheckResponse(tcpSocket, 220))
{
tcpSocket.Close();
return false;
}
```

is it the problem in my local system because of localhost?
Please help me. I am using this code from below link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5189/End-to-end-Email-Address-Verification-for-Applicat

Comment: Do you actually have &quot; in your code or should that be a double quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't try to implement your own SMTP client, use the one that comes with .NET: `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`.

Many SMTP servers require TLS, for example, which your code does not account for.

Furthermore, for security reasons most mailservers will not reveal if an email address in an `RCPT TO` line is valid or not. If a system can positively reveal an address exists then it can be used by spam harvesters. Consequently using a dry-run of an SMTP client should only be used to *validate* an email address (because of the complicated rules regarding valid email addresses). The *verification* (a separate concept from validation) must be performed manually by requiring the user to respond to an email sent to that address, there is no other way to be sure.